# desire2learn valence get users call giving 403 not authorized error

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am getting a 403 not authorized error with this call -> /d2l/api/lp/1.2/users/ and all it's variations with query parameters.

I have checked the permissions: Search for student, instructor, tutor, etc. and all the UIPs at Organization and Course Offering level for the calling user's role. All are  enabled. I've cascade enrolled this user from organization level to all levels. What am I missing which needs to be enabled to make this call work?

Comment: Are you able to make the call with another, more privileged, user context? I'd recommend starting with a no-privileges user and building up the perms until you can make the call you want, and then looking for diffs between your no-privs user role and the one you're really wanting to use, but you can try working backwards, too. Look for diffs from a more privileged role and starting taking away towards the problematic one... If you're having issues with this call with all users, then maybe connect to D2L support and send us a trace?

Comment: The user that I'm using has almost all the privileges. As per the "Investigating Roles Permissions" topic in Valence webpage, I see that even a non privileged user who's enrolled at the root level can make this call. I guess I should report this to d2l help desk. May be it's a configuration issue.

Comment: It would be useful to know exactly what the 403 you're getting back looks like. The 403 can result from various kinds of errors, at various layers in the webservice, so seeing a captured request/response traffic session would be very useful. I'm assuming that using the same code to sign API requests you're making _other_ calls that do work?

Comment: ["body"]=>
  string(41) "{"Errors":[{"Message":"Not Authorized"}]}"
["response"]=>
  string(285) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 14:10:54 GMT

{"Errors":[{"Message":"Not Authorized"}]}"
  ["http"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(403)
  }
}

Comment: That's the response body pasted above. Yes I'm using the same code to sign all the API requests and some of them are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- this is almost certainly that your calling user context doesn't have the permissions in place to make the call, for some reason. We do have this call working fine in our test environments, so I would encourage you to report this through D2L's support desk, and note that it's an API calling issue. You can help move it along significantly if you can provide a packet trace (via Fiddler or Wireshark) of a successful API call, and the not-good call, both outgoing request and response back along with your incident.

If, after opening the incident, you can report the INC number back here in a comment, I can try to expedite assistance at our end.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It was a permissions issue and the call -> `/d2l/api/lp/1.2/users/` needed the "User Management Tool" (something like that) permission, which my calling user didn't have at the root organization level. I was also getting an empty result set for the call -> `/d2l/api/lp/1.2/enrollments/orgUnits/{OrgUnitID}/users/` this needed the "View User Enrollments" permissions again at the root level.

After enabling those 2 permissions, I'm able to get the expected results.

Comment: That is correct -- currently, the API requires `View User Enrollments` at the root org level to view enrollments in any type of org unit.